# Lookup based on two columns and return sum in the new table

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, lookup-tables

I have a Excel file with 100,000 rows , first 10 rows:

```
    Date       Product   Sales_in_Units  Sales USD  
    1/1/2016    BM-D4     928            4,649    
    1/1/2016    BM-XN     266            685,740      
    1/2/2016    BM-B10    910            1,144    
    1/2/2016    PIB-H20   746            2,580,000    
    1/2/2016    PIB-H20   143            3,768,734   
    1/3/2016    VQR-GG2   269            570,794      
    1/3/2016    WS2-B18   106            432,400      
    1/4/2016    VQR-GG2   345            145,692      
    1/4/2016    BM-D4     234            747,541      
    1/5/2016    VQR-GG2   456            1,218    
    1/6/2016    PIB-H20   14             260,000 
...
```

I would like to be able to retrieve the `Sum` for specific `Date` and `Product` and fill the new table like (below). I was thinking this might be done with LOOKUP. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Date        Product         Total_Sales_in_Units    Total_Sales USD
1/1/2016    BM-XN           
1/3/2016    VQR-GG2         
1/4/2016    VQR-GG2         
1/6/2016    PIB-H20         
...
```

Comment: Are you going to accept one of these answers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `SUMIFS`, e.g. for sales in units:

```
= SUMIFS($C:$C,$A:$A,<date>,$B:$B,<product>)
```

and for sales USD:

```
= SUMIFS($D:$D,$A:$A,<date>,$B:$B,<product>)
```

Just replace `<date>` and `<product>` in formula above with whichever ones you want to look up.

Answer (score 2):

With data in columns **A** through **D**, in **E1** enter the desired date and in **F1** enter the desired product.

Then in **G1** enter:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A2:A100=E1)*(B2:B100=F1)*(C2:C100))
```

and in **H1** enter:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A2:A100=E1)*(B2:B100=F1)*(D2:D100))
```

[image]

Then fill down columns **E** through **H** with all the desired combinations you need.

Comment: Technically correct, although `--` is superfluous in this formula. Also `SUMIFS` should be preferred over `SUMPRODUCT` because it is significantly faster (I've heard about 3x to 5x faster for large datasets).